# Oracle 11g External Table error

Tags: database, oracle, external

I'm trying to run a simple external table program using oracle 11g on Linux VM. The problem is that I can't query any data from .txt files. 
 
Here's my code:

```
    CONN / as sysdba;

    CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DIR1 AS 'home/oracle/TEMP/X/';
    GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY DIR1 TO user;

    CONN user/password;

    CREATE TABLE gerada
    (
        field1   INT,
        field2   Varchar2(20)
    )
    ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
    (
            TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
            DEFAULT DIRECTORY DIR1
            ACCESS PARAMETERS 
            (
                    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
                    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
                    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
            )
            LOCATION ('registros.txt')
    )
    REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

    --Error starts here.
    SELECT * FROM gerada;

    DROP TABLE gerada;

    DROP DIRECTORY DIR1;
```

Here's the error message:

> ERROR at line 1:
>           ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
>           ORA-29400: data cartridge error
>           error opening file home/oracle/TEMP/X/GERADA_3375.log

And thats how registros.txt looks like:

```
    1234;hello world;
```

I've checked my permissions on DIR1 and I do have read/write permissions.

Any ideas?

Comment: do the owner of oracle-process has read/write permissions on DIR1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORA-29913 and ORA-29400 mean that you're unable to access to directory and/or file.

Looking carefully at the CREATE DIRECTORY command it looks like the path you're using may be mis-formatted.  Try putting a forward slash at the start of the path and removing the one at the end of the path when creating the directory - e.g. `CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY DIR1 AS '/home/oracle/TEMP/X';`.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Bob Jarvis, the code worked by using your suggestion AND removing the extension ".txt" from LOCATION. I just dont understand why!